# Transcription of Kurrenschrift letter snippet

Tags: palaeography, kurrent

I have this 4-page letter:

[Letter from Konrad Gradl to his Dearest Parents](https://www.familysearch.org/photos/artifacts/170353272)

[Letter from Konrad Gradl to his Dearest Parents](https://www.shorehub.us/humogen/media/Sources/Widenbauer-Pfeifer/LongLetter.pdf)

from Konrad Gradl who was the brother of my grandfather's grandmother, Anna Gradl.
I am trying to confirm that Sarah Gradl, who signed this letter in a different hand [lateinischehandschrift], is his wife and not eg. another sibling.

The Closing of the letter looks like this:

[image: Letter Closure / Brief Schließung]

The kurrenthandscrift deviates somewhat from canonical orthography,
but I think the postscript begins **"My wife sends best wishes to you all"** even though the capitol 'F' in "Frau" looks more like a lowercase canonical 'h'. There are some other 'P', 'Pf' and 'f' I'm not too sure about either.

My current attempt at transcription of the Letter Closing is still somewhat gibberish but begins "**Your obedient and grateful son**" and then continues:

> ```
>                        Euer gehorsammster
> ```
>
> Newport den 14ten               und dankbarer Sohn
>
> ```
> D[ez] 1848
>
>                                Konrad Gradl
> ```
>
> Meine Frau laß Euch allen viel wohl Grußen
> und bitt an mir, das ich anstatt für betten soll vor
> Sie, sie wolt auch etwas von Ihrer Schwieger-
> Mutter [.... Andeen] [Pfar] haben Sie [betht] alle
> Tage für Euch Sie gruß alle Euch im Grust
> der ganze Freundschaft.
>
> ```
>                     Sarah Graddle
> ```
>
> Conrad Gradl       Newporte
>
> Perry County     Pennsylvania
>
> ```
>            Northamerica
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this is definitely his wife, as it leads off with "Meine Frau." A sister would be "meine Schwester" and a daughter would be "meine Tochter."

I'm thinking that for your brackets you have:

1. au?? Andren
2. Pr??
3. perhaps betest (although that tense of the verb is off, but related to "pray")

General sense: My wife sends her best wishes. (Something about praying for them every day) She greeted all of you in the heart of all friendship.